# ORDERY BY in query with composite field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have next mysql table structure:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + value + month + year + type +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to do next select:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 Table
```

But with `ORDER BY` option. I wanna sort result on YEAR-MONTH composite field DESC.

I need something like this:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 Table
ORDER BY 
 YEAR-MONTH
DESC
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Table
ORDER BY 
    YEAR DESC, 
    MONTH DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT( year, month ) AS _sorter, *
FROM table
ORDER BY _sorter
```